# How do I limit the number of lines printed with the "backtrace" command in LLDB?

Tags: xcode, lldb

Under GDB, you could restrict the number of lines in a backtrace to e.g. the topmost 5 frames, by running the following command:

```
bt 5
```

In LLDB, this same command appears to print out the full backtrace of *thread 5*. I can't find any proper documentation on individual commands for LLDB - is it possible to print out only the last 5 lines of a backtrace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

`bt -c 5`

I found it along with a whole bunch of interesting LLDB info here: http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to the `-c X` option on that page, but it definitely works. Thanks!